# Is there a way to have custom attributes for members in Python 2.7 like those in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, python-2.7

For example, in C# I can do the following using reflection:

```
public class A
{
    object obj1;

    [MyCustumAttribute(data)]
    public object Obj1Property
    { get; set; }

    public A() {}
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type t = typeof(a);
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    attrs = props[0].GetCustomAttributes();

    //Do something with the properties based on their custom attributes
}
```

Note that I can do the same thing with A's methods, data members, etc. not just on properties.

Is there a way to do this same type of thing in Python 2.7?

Comment: I did not. I'm learning that I sometimes need to rethink my solution entirely when doing something in another language. I'm obviously thinking in C# here. I will need to re-think what I was originally trying to accomplish and make it Pythonic. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** After re-reading your question I realized that the reflection aspect wasn't addressed. The answer is still no from what I can find though. .NET reflection doesn't seem to address DLR types (e.g. IronPython, IronRuby). There is a reflection mechanism in python that you may be able to utilize though, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447529/635634 for details.

-

Not really, but you can sort of achieve the same effect using [DevHawk's solution](http://devhawk.net/2009/06/15/__clrtype__-metaclasses-simple-custom-attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

Something that could help to accomplish what you are trying to achieve are [python decorators](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) (extensive info on decorators [In this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators#answer-1594484))

Briefly, they are available since version 2.4 and allow you to wrap or decorate a function - In order to determine if a given function has a decorator you could attempt to evaluate using the functools library.

Another way that could help you accomplish this since you want to decorate a class are [Python MetaClasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949)